# How to import class from another file in java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call the function *getUrlContents(string)* inside my *seismic_text.java* file to my *MainActivity.java* file. How can I call the function from anywhere in the file? Any information or tip is appreciated. I include my files down below.

This is my *MainActivity.java*:

```
package bt.alfaquake;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import bt.alfaquake.seismic_text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    private static final int uniqueID = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    }    
}
```

This is my *seismic_text.java*:
        package bt.alfaquake;

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class seismic_text {

        public static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(theUrl);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    content.append(line + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return content.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does seismic_text. getUrlContents(url) works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call seismic_text.getUrlContents(url); but it will cause [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Just wrap this call to Simple AsynkTask.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
      try {
        return seismic_text.getUrlContents(url);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      // TODO handle result here
    }
  }
```

And call it from your code:

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call this in your MainActivty.java:

```
seismic_text.getUrlContents(url);
```

Comment: I think it will fail with NetworkOnMainTreadException - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: he can use async task for that, and my answer is according to the question, not that he have asked about the exception handling